# Phonegap save txt file of HTML form data

Tags: html, ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I need to use Phonegap to create an iOS app to save an HTML form. But, I'm not overly familiar with iOS or Phonegap. Can anyone point me in there correct direction?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="ipad" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hall Render - Resources Sign Up</title>
        <!-- Mobile Viewport -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
            <link href="assets/css/screen.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- jQuery -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3-min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery-validation-1.14.0-min.js"></script>
        <!-- Phonegap JS -->
            <script src="assets/js/phonegap.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/cordova.js"></script>
        <!-- Functions -->
            <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="onDeviceReady()">
        <!-- Begin Header -->
            <header>
                <div class="wrap">
                    <img src="assets/img/hall_render-logo.png" height="50" width="132">
                    <h1><strong>Health Law</strong> is our business.</h1>
                </div>
            </header>
        <!-- End Header -->
        <!-- Begin Secondary Header -->
            <section id="secondary-header">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="inner-wrap">
                        <h2><strong>Hall Render Alerts Provide</strong> up-to-date information</h2>
                        <p>on topics ranging from general health law to health care reform, HIPAA,<br>
                            employment law, health information technology and health care tax news.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- End Secondary Header -->
        <!-- Begin Main -->
            <section id="main">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="inner-wrap">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Sign Up to Receive Hall Render Resources</h3>
                            <p>
                                We appreciate your interest in our firm. As the nation’s largest law firm focused exclusively on matters specific to health care, our knowledge and experience allow us the opportunity to share the latest and most relevant health care news and practical takeaways directly with you. In an evolving industry such as health care, it’s crucial to stay up to date and informed. These email alerts are designed to help you do just that.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <form id="signup-form" method="get" action="">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                    <label for="cfirst-name">First Name: (required)</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="cfirst-name" name="firstname" tabindex="1">
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                    <label for="clast-name">Last Name: (required)</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="clast-name" name="lastname" tabindex="2">
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                    <label for="corganization">Organization:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="corganization" name="organization" tabindex="3">
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                    <label for="ctitle">Title:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="ctitle" name="title" tabindex="4">
                                </div>
                                <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                    <label for="cemail">Email: (required)</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="cemail" name="email" tabindex="5">
                                </div>
                                <input id="form-submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" tabindex="6">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- End Main -->
        <!-- Begin Secondary -->
            <section id="secondary">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="inner-wrap">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>Thank You</h3>
                            <p>
                                Thank you for signing up to receive Hall Render resources.<br>
                                You will be receiving an email from us soon with the latest health law news.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        <!-- End Secondary -->
        <!-- Begin Footer -->
            <footer>
                <div id="red-tab"></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div id="red-banner"></div>
                <div id="footer-hold">
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <p>
                            DENVER <span>|</span> DETROIT <span>|</span> INDIANAPOLIS <span>|</span> LOUISVILLE <span>|</span> MILWAUKEE <span>|</span> PHILADELPHIA <span>|</span> WASHINGTON, D.C.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        <!-- End Footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `functions.js` file:

```
(function($){

    /* On Page Ready */

        $(document).ready(function(){});

    /* On Page Load */

        $(window).load(function(){

            // Size differences
                var mainH = $('#main').outerHeight();
                var sheaH = $('#secondary-header').outerHeight();
                $('#secondary').height(mainH + sheaH - 40).hide();

            // Form Validation and Sumbit
                var form   = $('#signup-form');
                form.validate({
                    debug: true,
                    rules: {
                        firstname: {
                             required: true
                        },
                        lastname: {
                             required: true
                        },
                        email: {
                             required: true,
                             email: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        firstname: {
                            required: "Please enter your first name."
                        },
                        lastname: {
                            required: "Please enter your last name."
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: "Please enter your email."
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function(form){
                        form.submit();
                        $('#main, #secondary-header').fadeOut(400);
                        $('#secondary').fadeIn(500);
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location.reload(1);
                        }, 8000);
                    }
                });

        });

    /* On Window Resize */

        $(window).resize(function(){});

})(window.jQuery);
```

I'm using jQuery form validation and after validation it hides the form and shows a 'Thank You' and then reloads the page. Now, how do I get the form data to save to iOS file system? The app needs to be used offline and save info, reason why I need the info stored within iOS.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to review the PhoneGap documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html. Most of what you need to know is explained there. Have a go and come and ask again if you get stuck.

Comment: I have. I added `<feature name="File"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" /></feature><feature name="FileTransfer"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" /></feature>` in the `config.xml` to add `FileWriter` support. Guess I'm just not wrapping my head around it. Like how to save the fields, never over-writting existing data, and how to view the data later.

Comment: This is a decent example of file access in Cordova/PhoneGap http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/05/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file. As for the rest you just need to figure out an algorithm to follow along the lines of 1. Read submitted form data, 2. Read existing stored data from file, 3. Compare stored data with submitted form data and figure out what data needs updating, 4. Update it, 5. Write updated data to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I realized that I was going about this all WRONG. I needed the form data to post to a database. The database is used to collect all submitted form data. I believe the .txt file idea would be overwritten every single time the form data was submitted. So, I created two pages. One page to fill out and submit the form. One page to view all form entries and to export and clear database.

index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hall Render - Resources Sign Up</title>
    <!-- Mobile Viewport -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link href="assets/css/screen.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3-min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-validation-1.14.0-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Cordova JS -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- Functions -->
        <script src="assets/js/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady(){
                var db = window.openDatabase("HALLRENDER", 1.0, "App database",200000);
                // Size differences
                    var mainH = $('#main').outerHeight();
                    var sheaH = $('#secondary-header').outerHeight();
                    $('#secondary').height(mainH + sheaH - 40).hide();
                // Form Validation and Sumbit
                    var form   = $('#signup-form');
                    form.validate({
                        debug: true,
                        rules: {
                            firstname: {
                                 required: true
                            },
                            lastname: {
                                 required: true
                            },
                            email: {
                                 required: true,
                                 email: true
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            firstname: {
                                required: "Please enter your first name."
                            },
                            lastname: {
                                required: "Please enter your last name."
                            },
                            email: {
                                required: "Please enter your email."
                            }
                        },
                        submitHandler: function(form){
                            $('#main, #secondary-header').fadeOut(400);
                            $('#secondary').fadeIn(500);
                            db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
                        }
                    });
            }
            // Populate the database
                function populateDB(tx) {
                    // Form Variables
                        var firstName    = $('#cfirst-name').val();
                        var lastName     = $('#clast-name').val();
                        var organization = $('#corganization').val();
                        var title        = $('#ctitle').val();
                        var email        = $('#cemail').val();

                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PEOPLE (Email, FirstName, LastName, Title, Organization)');
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PEOPLE (Email, FirstName, LastName, Title, Organization) VALUES ("'+email+'", "'+firstName+'", "'+lastName+'", "'+title+'", "'+organization+'")');

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        window.location.reload(1);
                    }, 8000);
                }
            // Transaction error callback
                function errorCB(tx, err) {
                    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
                }
            // Transaction success callback
                function successCB() {
                    console.log("Entry saved!");
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
    <!-- Begin Header -->
        <header>
            <div class="wrap">
                <!-- SOMETHING -->
            </div>
        </header>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Begin Secondary Header -->
        <section id="secondary-header">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner-wrap">
                    <!-- SOMETHING -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <!-- End Secondary Header -->
    <!-- Begin Main -->
        <section id="main">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner-wrap">
                    <div class="text">
                        <!-- SOMETHING -->
                    </div>
                    <form id="signup-form">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                <label for="cfirst-name">First Name: (required)</label>
                                <input type="text" id="cfirst-name" name="firstname" tabindex="1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                <label for="clast-name">Last Name: (required)</label>
                                <input type="text" id="clast-name" name="lastname" tabindex="2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                <label for="corganization">Organization:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="corganization" name="organization" tabindex="3">
                            </div>
                            <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                <label for="ctitle">Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="ctitle" name="title" tabindex="4">
                            </div>
                            <div class="label-input-wrap">
                                <label for="cemail">Email: (required)</label>
                                <input type="email" id="cemail" name="email" tabindex="5">
                            </div>
                            <input id="form-submit" type="submit" value="Sign Up" tabindex="6">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <!-- End Main -->
    <!-- Begin Secondary -->
        <section id="secondary">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="inner-wrap">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h3>Thank You</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <!-- End Secondary -->
</body>
```

export.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hall Render - Export</title>
    <!-- Mobile Viewport -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Main Stylesheet -->
        <link href="assets/css/screen.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3-min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Plugins -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-validation-1.14.0-min.js"></script>
    <!-- Cordova JS -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- Functions -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady(){
                var db = window.openDatabase("HALLRENDER", 1.0, "App database",200000);
                db.transaction(queryDB);
                $('#dump').click(function(){
                    db.transaction(dropDB);
                    alert('Database Cleared!');
                });
            }
            // Query Table Rows
                function queryDB(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM PEOPLE', [], querySuccess);
                }
            // Get Table Rows
                function querySuccess(tx,result){
                    var status = document.getElementById("status");
                    var people = "";
                    var len = result.rows.length;
                    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                        people = people + '<li>'+result.rows.item(i).Email+','+result.rows.item(i).FirstName+','+result.rows.item(i).LastName+','+result.rows.item(i).Title+','+result.rows.item(i).Organization+'</li>';
                    }
                    status.innerHTML = people;
                    $("#status").listview("refresh");
                }
            // Delete Database
                function dropDB(tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE PEOPLE');
                }

            // File Writer
                function saveCourseToFile() {
                    console.log("checkpoint 1");
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
                    alert('CSV File Created!');
                }
                function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
                    console.log("checkpoint 2");
                    console.log("Opened file system: " + fileSystem.name);
                    fileSystem.root.getFile("export.csv", {create:true, exclusive:false}, gotFileEntry, onFSError);
                }
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    console.log("checkpoint 3");
                    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSError);
                }
                function gotFileWriter(writer) {
                    var entries =   $('#status').find('li').filter(function() {
                                        return $(this).find('ul').length === 0;
                                    }).map(function(i, e) {
                                        return $(this).text();
                                    }).get().join('\n');
                    var dbEntries = 'Email,First Name,Last Name,Title,Organization\n'+entries;
                    writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
                    console.log("checkpoint 4: write success!");
                    };
                    writer.write(dbEntries);
                }
                function onFSError(err) {
                    console.log(err.code);
                }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="onDeviceReady()">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <ol id="status" nam="status"></ol>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button id="export" onclick="saveCourseToFile()">Create .csv File Export</button>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button id="dump">Clear Database</button>
        <p id="warning"><strong>WARNING: </strong>Export to .csv <em>BEFORE</em> clearing database!!</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="contents"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This might look crazy. But, it works for what I was trying to accomplish. Take form data, save it locally, then export info into .csv file. Hopefully this gives someone else some insight into a similar problem. Thanks to everyone for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

- First install the cordova file plugin. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html

  ```
  cordova plugin install org.apache.cordova.file
  ```
- Capture the text from the form HTML with JQuery (#id).val() or document.getElementById('id').value.
- Create the function to Write file like this:

My data captured from the form

```
var dataForm = $('#someId).val(); // All your text from the form.
```

Function for require File System and create file.

```
function createTxtFile(){
      //  Request File System
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem){
        fileSystem.root.getFile("myTxt.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false},
           function(fileEntry){
          // Create File
          fileEntry.createWriter(WriteText, fail);
      }, fail);
    },
    fail
    );
  }
```

Function for write text.

```
  function WriteText(writer) {
      writer.onwriteend = function(evt){ // Fired when end write.
        console.log("End write text in file");

    };
    writer.write(dataForm);
}
```

Comment: Ok. This helped a lot. Not sure if I have it working though. Where does it save, or create, the text file?

Comment: /Users/YourUser/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/CF2A9018-49B9-4DE6-91FC-EA76CB435FC8/Documents/

but this can vary according to operating system version